# Selecting duplicates from a temp table from multiple Columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file loaded into a Spark Cluster. I would like to identify all the duplicate records based on few columns  and write them into a RDD. I tried using Spark SQL but could not get the task done.

Comment: Can you please provide more info. Probably Json schema and what is the field that you are looking for

Comment: can you state the purpose, as there maybe other ways.  
you can sort (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#sort(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) and iterate through

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have two columns ("column1" and "column2") that you can use to find if the records are duplicated, you can try the following (using Spark SQL):

```
val newData = data
  .groupBy("column1", "column2")
  .agg(count("*").as("cnt"))
  .where(col("cnt") > 1)
```

If you need all columns, you can join the resulting dataframe with the original data:

```
val finalData = newData.join(data, Seq("column1", "column2"))
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively, if you have a HiveContext, you can use a Window Function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val newData = data
  .withColumn("cnt", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("column1", "column2"))
  .where(col("cnt") > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not get what do you mean by identifying duplicates. If the data is schema based as you mentioned can get help from `Spark SQL`. Convert it to `DataFrame` and try the following if you just want to remove duplicates from groups.
`df.dropDuplicates(List("colA" , "colB"))`

Comment: I want to select the duplicates rather than dropping them. I want a place to store all my duplicate records.